# Is this the best index possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

I have a table like:

CREATE TABLE `ph_numbers` (
  `service_area_code` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_number` (`number`(4))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

I want to query this table based on the number column. The number is a phone number with 10 digits, first 4 of these digits can be used as an opertor identifier. The table contains about 200 million rows.

What can I do to improve the querying?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to improve the query is make `number` be the primary key of the table. In InnoDB, primary key lookups are less expensive than secondary index lookups.

But that means you can't use a prefix index for the `number`.

I wonder why you're using VARCHAR(20) for a 10-digit number. Wouldn't VARCHAR(10) fit more snugly?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I am using varchar 20 in place of 10 because the source from where I fetch the data can be unreliable at times and may give phone number of length more than 10. I do not want to lose the data in such a case.